# Typescript Conditional Date/string Return Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

How can I apply a conditional function return type of *string* or *Date*, based upon the *value* param type?

Forced to type assert the function call `<Date>toggleDateString(stringValue)` due to the following error:

`Argument of type 'string | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.`

```js
const toggleDateString = (value: Date | string) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        ...
        return some-Date
    } else {
        ...
        return some-string
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: @brk Updated post with the issue I'm running into.

Comment: can you show the complete function how you are calling it

Comment: @brk This is what I don't want to be forced to do... `<Date>toggleDateString(stringValue)`. Would like to return Date type only from string value, and vise versa.

Comment: Are you trying to provide return type info based on the parameter type? (I.e. f(string): date and f(date): string)? I don't think the compiler can handle this with a single function implementation. Can you instead use an overloaded function?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXk1QW) meet your needs?  Arrow functions are a little more annoying than function statement to make either overloaded or generic-with-conditional-return type, and in either case you have to take some responsibility for the implementation typing, but at least from the call side it would work.  Let me know if you want an answer written up for this, or if there's something about it that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @andrew Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I attempted to use a type definition, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, that worked perfectly. Is that using a generic?

Comment: yes, it's a [generic](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function whose return type is a [conditional type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). I have to go now so someone might answer this before I get to; if so, hopefully they will point to [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), the issue asking for better support for such functions... right now you pretty much need a [type assertion](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to get the implementation to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two features in TypeScript that let you define functions where the return type depends on the parameter types: [*overloaded*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) functions and [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions.  They both have caveats.

---

**Overloaded functions**

Overloaded functions have multiple call signatures, and when you call the function the compiler chooses which call signature by checking each one in order against the inputs.  Here's an overloaded call signature type for `toggleDateString`:

```
declare const toggleDateString: {
  (value: Date): string;
  (value: string): Date;
}

toggleDateString(new Date()).toUpperCase(); // string
toggleDateString("hello").getFullYear() // Date
```

Overloaded function caveats:

- When you implement an overloaded function via *function statement*, you declare each call signature first, and then provide the implementation:

  ```
    function toggleDateString(value: Date): string;
    function toggleDateString(value: string): Date;
    function toggleDateString(value: Date | string) {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return someDate;
      } else {
        return someString;
      }
    }
  ```

  The compiler does a little bit of checking to see that the implementation isn't completely incompatible with a combination of the call signatures, but it allows some unsafe implementations.  It just doesn't really try to verify that the implementation is correct.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235).  You therefore need to be careful inside an overloaded function implementation statement that you are doing the right thing.  For example, the following compiles with no error:

  ```
    function toggleDateString(value: Date): string;
    function toggleDateString(value: string): Date;
    function toggleDateString(value: Date | string) {
      if (typeof value !== 'string') { // <-- oops
        return someDate;
      } else {
        return someString;
      }
    }
  ```
- When you try implement an overloaded function via an *expression* (like a `function` expression or an arrow function) you have sort of the opposite problem:  The compiler still does not really try to verify that the implementation is correct, but now instead of allowing unsafe implementations, it will warn about safe ones.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#38622](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38622).  For example:

  ```
  const toggleDateString: { // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
    // Type '(value: Date | String) => string | Date' is not assignable to type 
    // '{ (value: Date): string; (value: string): Date; }'.
      (value: Date): string;
      (value: string): Date;
    } = (value: Date | String) => {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return someDate;
      } else {
        return someString;
      }
    }
  ```

  So in order to proceed there you'd need to suppress the error via something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

  ```
    const toggleDateStringAssert = ((value: Date | String) => {
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return someDate;
      } else {
        return someString;
      }
    }) as {
      (value: Date): string;
      (value: string): Date;
    }; // no error now
  ```

  which brings you back to allowing unsafe things (as you'd see if you change `===` to `!==` again).
- When calling overloaded functions, the compiler will only allow you to call one of the call signatures at a time.  It does not "combine" call signatures; see [microsoft/TypeScript#41407](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107). If the compiler cannot figure out which call signature to invoke, there will be an error:

  ```
    toggleDateString(new Date()); // okay
    toggleDateString("someString"); // okay
    toggleDateString(Math.random() < 0.5 ? new Date() : "someString"); // error!
    // ------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // No overload matches this call.
    function oops<T extends Date | string>(t: T) {
      toggleDateString(t); // error!
      // No overload matches this call.
    }
  ```
- When manipulating or inspecting the types of overloaded functions in the type system, the compiler will generally pretend that only the first or the last call signature exists.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26591](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26591) for more information.  This sometimes ends up having strange effects:

  ```
    type OutputOfToggleDateString = ReturnType<typeof toggleDateString>
    // type OutputOfToggleDateString = Date // <-- just Date?!
  ```

---

**Generic functions**

For a generic function you have just one call signature, but there is a generic type parameter that will be inferred based on the input when the function is called.  You need to express the desired return type in terms of the generic type parameter.  In the general case this could require [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  Here's an implementation:

```
const toggleDateString = <T extends Date | string>(value: T): T extends Date ? string : Date => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return someDate as any;
  } else {
    return someString as any;
  }
}
```

You can call these functions in more circumstances, as there's a single call signature:

```
toggleDateString(new Date()); // okay, string
toggleDateString("someString"); // okay, Date
toggleDateString(Math.random() < 0.5 ? new Date() : "someString"); // okay, string | Date
function okay<T extends Date | string>(t: T) {
  toggleDateString(t); // okay, T extends Date ? string : Date
}
```

And the compiler is a bit better about manipulating the types of these in the type system:

```
type OutputOfToggleDateString = ReturnType<typeof toggleDateString>
// type OutputOfToggleDateString = string | Date
```

Generic function with conditional return type caveats:

- You may have noticed that the function above uses type assertions `as any` inside the implementation.  Like overloads, the compiler really cannot verify that the function implementation satisfies the call signature:

  ```
  const togDateStringUgh = <T extends Date | string>(value: T): T extends Date ? string : Date => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return someDate; // error! 'Date' is not assignable to 'T extends Date ? string : Date'
    } else {
      return someString; // error! 'string' is not assignable to 'T extends Date ? string : Date'
    }
  }
  ```

  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for more information.  For now you need some sort of type assertion to prevent errors.
- Generic conditional types are a bit weirder looking and harder to explain than overloads.

---

Personally I tend to avoid overloads and prefer generic functions, but it is a matter of opinion.  Either way will work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJLwD2wUALklGZACIhXIC8SwEA7kkywBQBKANxES5SjTqQAylQBOAS2ABzAFy0FylUnYAiGfWRylqvaMJiO4aHERIA8gDcI8jGRAATCJ7xErJN7wGCDyyBLUSFRkKioYEHwQJtoaBMQkGfxOmACuEBqJghrUpioWGZnZGHnFWqpFvMwQ5RkAvv7pJEK6AHxRMXEJTcmq-Jw8iUKCAHTRAKowMK4AwiBQEELCSAD025qlAUjdrH3RsfGJIyr8egAWEBjuejMqEFQAYjmPAJoQod27RosDokdrpUCQWAIZDODCeORNSDAGhpQ4AMxywHgVEUFH65yGLCuWVy+SBEAaJW0LRIGKxOLxZ0Glzq1yqNX22gaiRpSDp2NxwHxzOGrJJ1TJiSQAB9OfU-J0Moo0UcqABPJZkFXstisdgAcipqn1ggVFQqYSoOXkQukhOah1BSAe6zN5pIluttqMV15oMOYPRmIFjIGF1FpQcZBgUHFHMKtVKvP5DKFTPDRNZUZjcbJRpU3KayeDqeFGaSWejsZ1BSaMrlBbdFWVqo1EC1SB1SAAhHqkIbWSa8Ds9gAeAC046QXBAiioABpp-IKDp4Pd4ABrR0ZT022hGHnb1rOjCutLuj1vL372Ssv1IMEVQOWdLPkgQ2zQxxOOEAUQAHjAYRQFAgoKocEQ0Om9pXKkI7OvIy7yN226AkgAB+mFYdhOHoUgE7jqhewACptv2ua1iw9ZXKaJwNvWiT6kgihQBwZA0GsoEqKAABG8T9FEZFEf2uBHDW5KUneYmkomXKUc0D76tM24URJsmqPeqn5oWLC8se7CqVKso0b0TZKiq-Dqpq2qkrofYDqUQ7nheu7eowRZHieZ7bpeVp7navpHgGHQQRQkTQSypQAIIga4NAGYZdbGaytF9M5zYWVZ7Y2RKdkGvmTk+Ugrk3va97Hi6yDpeaJUBXeQWKq0pprGZXTiQmDaaeJ2nyXpFggg+A0flC9irI82jOK47heKxqKKimYERRG2iJSwklJkG9KLWGMFit1KW9ZtIZpjtkUre1SUNqa1UkC2llth2XZ6vlg7XUVtUHh5ipOpVrU7le-k+vV32DY1A0kEtmalGM3DklMWyAmQG4gGqhyQxW0N6HVpTPAjexIyjaOnctowALLMLc0zyCAwCePQ3SjkgAAM0wAKxIAA-BwsOTKaGhY0DOMiPBrhIShiqApOUvS1LfS4fLCuK0r8uHICAByZBIGQLhuB4vhgMwa7QFEtwsaQmAYMp80lmBZBVqOxHOv+LC06xRkNj0lkaMRb0g+jxJUMLgKi2QyHCRrWs69N+uG-crFUKbrHoI8VtPuDglLI4ORUDA2cOGixHE1D2i6EgABKAPAKRSyjllHb+6yPSq3sWVZznecF0XGMl+wUqAgRSAAFY5JEiQc+LVhvtYkJ2MgADiECcEo8DLBQnhzoKmBmZBZa7aUpcO07LueG7l35p74k+97R+Lyf5Kc-R8mmTdzGZQ9OV5Hl-YFb7F7FZXpUpQtRpmqcqXkqrvQAdjEuwDgCgIamnF8FQG7Q3GHDQQQd8bIzVIufMRMCRnVGALW8Qs8Za2wYuRI+CRTFzJhTKmNM6ZgAZszNmD80G8yQPzaBZhMHkJRrg1kDEmhHVLATNUh8IDO1vqfKispz5eyQD7P6KCVqBzIeIxcjspHH1kcgLm+YuHkmCkgjIrcHDZ1zlQfOhcCEkx0OwCufkq5tlru-XehCVBNwli3MiFj27WM7nY2hDj6KyioS+UKkgPH2LmCoW4B9tHSNdvfeRjdVJXyUTfFJUoDFCKfnRF+d064f11C9Ryv8XJQM+rpEWiFQ7diUWRfUjFmKsWAOxJAnFFDcRAHxZA0QM7IH1Ek3R988n73kvqTyv0X6+WvDwsodSxZNMzg5bQTEzYdI4iBHpvF+KDNbiM7Jd9cmP3JNMkGj42ghVfEQVoQA)

Answer (score 0):

Solution in comments is fine, though generics seem like using a cannon to kill flies in this situation. I believe it would be easier and nicer to convert this function from arrow to normal one (anyway you don't seem to use `this` keyword here so it's not a problem) and use overloads

```
function toggleDateString(value: Date): string
function toggleDateString(value: string): Date
function toggleDateString(value: string | Date): string | Date {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return Date.parse(value) // or whatever
    } else {
        return value.toString() // or whatever
    }
}
```